mocking local storage in jest works only with toHaveBeenCalledWith but cannot get the current status?
I want to check the status of ls after the action, but it is returning undefined. How can I mock the storage? Is toHaveBeenCalledWith the only way, or is there another way to check the functions?


describe('setTheme', () => {
    it('should set theme to light', () => {
      // Dispatch Action
      store.dispatch(setTheme('light'));
      // Mocked Expected
      expect(store.getState().misc.theme).toEqual('light');
      // Check localStorage
      expect(localStorage.setItem).toHaveBeenCalledWith('theme', JSON.stringify('light'));
      // Check if the theme is correctly set in localStorage
      const storedThemeItem = localStorage.getItem('theme');

      if (storedThemeItem !== null && storedThemeItem !== undefined) {
        const storedTheme = JSON.parse(storedThemeItem);
        expect(storedTheme).toEqual('light');
      } else {
        throw new Error('Theme not found in localStorage');
      }
    });
    }



